# GEOID not found in TIGERLINE Shapefiles

Tags: gis, fips, census, tigris, tiger-census

Trying to use the TIGER/Line shapefiles and convert some GEOIDs (census track number) of Georgia into LAT/LONG in R. After the first round of conversion, I still have about 50k unmatched GEOIDs.

Some of these leftovers include
133179801001
130319902004
130670311074
131131402052
130890234052
132231206005
...

I did a couple of round of googling, it seems like they do exist, but why are they not in the TIGER/Line Shapefiles?

Answer (score 0):

It could be that the date of your TIGER-Line file is different from your other (data.census.gov?) file. There are several reasons why GEOIDs change including: a name change (or name CORRECTION) or a significant boundary change or annexation. 50K sounds like the magnitude of change in census tracts between decades.